# Extracting values from a table row based on row data - JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm attempting to parse a HTML document using JSoup. What I am trying to do is extract the table data of a specific row. I want to be able to select said row using the value of the href attribute or the value of the `<a></a>` tags.

```
<tbody>
   <tr class="even">
      <td><a href="link-1">Link_1</a></td>
      <td align="center">9</td>
      <td align="center">9</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="odd">
      <td><a href="link-2">Link_2</a></td>
      <td align="center">22</td>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="even">
      <td><a href="link-3">Link_3</a></td>
      <td align="center">22</td>
      <td align="center">7</td>
      <td align="center">1</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Selecting the whole table is easy, I can just use the following:

```
Document htmlRawData = Jsoup.parse(deviceMetricData.toString());
Elements htmlMetrics = htmlRawData.select("tbody > tr > td[align]");

htmlMetrics.stream().forEach((ele) -> {
   System.out.println(ele.toString());
});
```

This is only ever ideal when the table has a single row. If it has many then selecting a specific row based on the value of the first cell becomes more tricky.

Can anyone help get me started or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want.  Can you give an example of the output you want to extract from that table?  There are two obvious options: select all the first cells, then iterate over them selecting rows by their index; select all the table data into Java data structures and do your filtering with loops as usual.  (I can't get back to you with an answer for at least a few hours, but adding example output will help everyone who's trying to answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that can traverse through `DOM` tree.

If you only know that there will be always the same structure (`a` inside `td` which is inside `tr`) then you can make it as follows:

```
Element link = document.select("tbody > tr > td > a[href=\"link-1\"]").first();
link.parent().parent().children().forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can also filter all rows by occurence of this very `href` value:

```
final Elements rows = document.select("tbody > tr");
rows
    .stream()
    .filter(tr -> !tr.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("href", "link-1").isEmpty())
    .findFirst()
    .map(Element::children)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Or by using select:

```
final Elements rows = document.select("tbody > tr");
rows
    .stream()
    .filter(tr -> !tr.select("a[href=\"link-1\"").isEmpty())
    .findFirst()
    .map(Element::children)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```